# Azure devops API sendmail getting 204 but no e-mail

Tags: azure, devops

I am trying to send an e-mail from an azure build pipeline, I have checked OAuth Access Token checkbox on the agent, and here's the code that gets a 204 status code, but no e-mail is recieved, I appreciate your help

```
    function SentEmail{
    param(
[string]$org,
[string]$project,
[string]$token
)
    $header = @{"Accept"="application/json";Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token))))}
    $uri="https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$requestBody =
@"
{
    "message": {
    "body" : "Test Body",
    "cc" : {},
    "to" : {
        "tfsIds" : ["HARD_CODED_MY_TFSID"],
        "emailAddresses": ["HARD_CODED_MY_EMAIL"]
    },
    "replyTo" : {},
    "subject" : "Test Subject"
    }
}
"@
    Write-Host "uri: $uri"
    Write-Host "body: $requestBody"
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body $requestBody -Method POST -Headers $header -ContentType 'application/json'
}

SentEmail -org "ORG_HERE" -project "PROJECT_HERE" -token "$env:System_AccessToken"
```

Comment: Found out you have to include a workitem in the message, now it is working, thanks.

Comment: how do you include a work item in the message? Thanks

Comment: @InfiniteLoop here's a gist, thanks https://gist.github.com/pamanes/4bd1664f1f394efbc111bcf44a838681